# php, json to specific string

Tags: php, arrays, json

By POST I get this JSON (can have more than 3 values in it)

```
{"preferences":["Theater","Opera","Danse"]}
```

Well, I need to get

```
array('Theater', 'Opera', 'Degustation')
```

json_decode doesn't work.
Do you have any ideas please?
Thank you by advance

Comment: What do you mean by "json-decode doesn't work"? What happens when you try it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't change the third value to another at least, but otherwise should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the ***true*** parameter:

```
$jsonData = '{"preferences":["Theater","Opera","Danse"]}';

$arrayData = json_decode($jsonData, true );

var_dump($arrayData['preferences']);
```

The last line outputs the following:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Theater"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Opera"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Danse"
}
```

Which is what you want. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the TRUE parameter, exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have used the output of the `json_decode()` function as an associated array while you hadn't have told the function to provide an associated array for you, or vice versa!! However, the following will get you the array at the `preferences` index:

```
<?php
$decoded = json_decode('{"preferences":["Theater","Opera","Danse"]}', true); // <-- note the second parameter is true.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($decoded['preferences']); // output: Array ( [0] => Theater [1] => Opera [2] => Danse )
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Note the usage of the output of the function as an associated array :)
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you also, same answer than above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sim100 Your welcome, but I've posted the answer more than a quarter of an hour earlier!!

Answer (score 0):

That JSON string is wrapped in an object (denoted by curly braces {}). json_decode will give you the wrapper object whose "preferences" property is the array you're looking for.

```
$wrapper = json_decode($json_string);
$array = $wrapper->preferences;
```

json_decode might also be unavailable if you're using and older version of php. In that case you should try a php json library.